# Conditionally check if a value that may at times be undefined is not equal to another value?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

```
var query = [], name = 'name';

if (body.displayName !== req.user.displayName) {
    query.push({
        displayName: name
    });
}
```

This works, but I've run into a use-case where `req.user.displayName === undefined`.

Intuitively, it would seem `undefined` would also not be equal to `body.displayName`, but of course it throws an error:

> "cannot read property of undefined"

Is there anyway to have this conditionally check if the value is `undefined` and also not equal to `body.displayName` within the same if statement, or is the only way to nest this within another if statement:

```
if (req.user.displayName !== undefined) { }
```

Comment: Are you sure that what is `undefined` is `req.user.displayName`? It's seems more likely, given the error, that it's either `req` or `req.user` (or perhaps `body`) that's `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So figure out what is undefined

```
console.log(req);
console.log(req.user);
```

I am assuming the bug is that user is not set. If that can be true, than you do not have an issue. If it should have a user than you have a bug.

But the basic check would use a truthy check to make sure the object s there. It could be either one of the following depending what is undefined.

```
if (req && req.user && req.user.displayName !== body.displayName)
```

or

```
if (req.user && req.user.displayName !== body.displayName)
```

or if `body` is `undefined`, you would need to do the check the other way.

Answer (score 1):

That error cannot come from `req.user.displayName` being `undefined`. It comes from trying to read a property of something that's undefined, which means that the culprit is that `body`, `req` or `req.user` is `undefined`.

Here's a transcript from node.js:

```
> body = {displayName: "foo"}
{ displayName: 'foo' }
> req = {user: {displayName: undefined}}
{ user: { displayName: undefined } }
> req.user
{ displayName: undefined }
> req.user.displayName
undefined
> body.displayName !== req.user.displayName
true
```

No problems at all, even though `req.user.displayName` is `undefined`.

You don't need to change your `if` test; you need to track down why one of those other objects is `undefined`.